# Can I compile a Delphi project to run on ubuntu?

Tags: deb, pascal

I need to compile a Delphi (pascal) project to run on Ubuntu. It has a GUI and it is supposed to communicate with an external device so I cannot use WINE to just execute the .exe file. Is there any way to create a .deb file out of the source code?

Comment: If Delphi can cross-compile your code for Linux as target, then chances are it will run. You probably don't need a `.deb` file though; instead of Windows executable (`.exe`), your Delphi compiler should produce a Linux executable (these usually have no extension) that you just have to copy to Linux machine, give it executable attribute and run there. However, some dependencies (libraries) may be needed to run it. You need to consult your Delphi documentation; that's the first source of information for you.

Comment: And usually a best answer to questions like this one is: read the documentation, then experiment trying to implement what you read there. Repeat until succeeded. You could also start with checking if your `.exe` file actually won't run using WINE; you seem to be sure that you can't use WINE to run it, but you didn't state that you have actually tried and it doesn't run.

Answer (score 1):

FMXLinux (Embarcadero Software License) for Delphi,  this awesome component you can work on Delphi to develop amazing applications, this way you don’t need to learn another language and how to deal with a new IDE, simple and powerful this component will make your life easier .

To install it just open your Delphi, go to ‘Get It Package Manager’ and search for FMXLinux, select the package and click install, read and accept the terms of use.

Restart Delphi IDE and that’s it, you can start to develop and deploy your beautiful and powerful Linux applications.

Comment: I cannot find FMXLinux anywhere. If it is not present on the community edition and/or trial, I am not really going to buy a subscription for something I don't know if it works for my application.

Comment: https://www.fmxlinux.com/

Comment: From the fmxlinux.com website: _Note: FmxLinux requires Delphi for Linux compiler, which is part of Enterpise/Architect Editions only._

Answer (score 0):

In my case I could not find FMXLinux because I was using a trial license. I have learned that some components are hidden when using the *GetIt Package Manager* - when using  trial license

Comment: Thanks for that. I think that's what was happening